# Stringの連結時のOutOfMemoryExceptionを回避する方法

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vb.net

VB.netでのWindowsアプリケーション開発をしています。
String文字列の連結においてOutOfMemoryExceptionのエラーがスローされます。

手法としてはSingleの数値をカンマで区切り、1000個のカンマ区切り文字列を作成します。
その文字列は「temp_Str as String」の変数に格納していくのですが、
大型のループ処理で10万件以上作成されたところで上記のエラーが発生します。
（時間にして2～3時間程度経過した時点）

少なくとも数100万件の処理を行いたいのですが、
うまくメモリー管理をする方法はないでしょうか？
今現在GC.CollectやRemove等の処理は入れているのですが、あまり効果がありません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「1000個のカンマ区切り文字列を作成」や「temp_Str as Stringの変数に格納していく」の箇所は、具体的にコードを提示されると質問としてより良くなると思います。

Comment: @nbx1508 コードを見せてもらえないと OutOfMemoryException が発生する可能性が複数あり断定出来ません。抽象コードで良いので見せて貰えますか。そして出来ればどの行でGC.Collectをやったのかコメントで残して貰えるとアドバイスが貰えるかと思います。

Comment: マルチポストですね？せめてその旨を書きましょう。マナー違反です。http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9136502.html

Comment: http://hanatyan.sakura.ne.jp/vbnetbbs/wforum.cgi?mode=allread&no=11559
http://qa.itmedia.co.jp/qa9099749.html
ひどいですね～

Answer (score 3):

「String文字列の連結にはStringBuilderを使うのがいいですよ」と回答を書こうとしてコード例を作ったところ、件数が多すぎてStringBuilderを使ってもOutofMemoryExceptionが出てしまいました。

件数が多くてメモリ上で全件を処理できない場合、行ごとに処理をするよう発想を変えるのがベターだと思います。

この方法なら数100万件を超えても、ディスク容量の許す限りエラーにはなりません。  
※分散処理でDBにでも格納するのがベストかもしれませんが、環境のセットアップなどが必要になるためここでは扱いません。

以下は `C:\tmp123456789.txt` というファイルを一時的に書き出して、各行ごとに処理してからファイルを消すサンプルコードです。
手元の環境では1万行に対して30秒ほどで出力が、80秒ほどで全体の処理が終わりました。

```vb
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim tmpFile = "C:\tmp123456789.txt" 

        Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch
        stopwatch.Start()

        Dim rnd As Random = New Random
        '件数が多いのでStringBuilderでもメモリ不足
        'Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        'ファイルを開いておいて逐次出力
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(tmpFile, False)
        'ある程度データがたまったら自動書き出しするモード
        writer.AutoFlush = True

        '10の5乗 = 10,000
        For i = 1 To Math.Pow(10, 5)
            Dim list As List(Of Single) = New List(Of Single)
            '行データ作成
            For j = 1 To 1000
                list.Add(CType(rnd.NextDouble(), Single))
            Next
            '行データ出力(全件データを一気に扱う必要がなければ、StreamWriterを使わずにここで各行の処理をしてもいいです)
            writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", list))
        Next
        writer.Close()
        Dim msg1 = String.Format("テンポラリファイル作成時間: {0} 秒", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)
        Console.WriteLine(msg1)
        'ファイル出力が目的ならここでおしまい。

        'テンポラリファイルの各行を読み出しながら処理
        Dim total As Double = 0
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(tmpFile)

        ' 読み込みできる文字がなくなるまで繰り返す
        While (Not reader.EndOfStream)
            ' ファイルを 1 行ずつ読み込む
            Dim line = reader.ReadLine
            '何か処理する(ここではサンプルとして加算している)
            For Each s In line.Split(",")
                total += Single.Parse(s)
            Next
        End While
        reader.Close()
        '後始末
        File.Delete(tmpFile)

        Dim msg2 = String.Format("処理完了時間: {0} 秒", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)
        Console.WriteLine(msg2)
        Console.WriteLine("合計値は {0} です。", total)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: StringBuilderでも単純にメモリが足りないことを確認されたのですね！このレベルのデータ量では、Streamに書き出すことが確実ですね。

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。メモリが十分かつ文字列全体が2GBを越えなければyhataさんの回答の方が優れていますね。

Comment: ご質問させていただいたものです。大変参考になり
String.Join(",", list)で解決いたしました。
本当に助かりました。

Answer (score 3):

yhataさんの指摘も踏まえて回答を改めます。

String結合を無制限に繰り返すことが原因で`OutOfMemoryException`が発生する場合ですが、例外が表しているようにメモリ不足の可能性があります。32bitアプリケーションでは2GBのメモリを使用できますが、その全てがデータに使えるわけではないため、それよりも少ない使用量でも`OutOfMemoryException`が発生します。
`String`の代わりに`StringBuilder`を使用することで処理速度は向上しますが、処理可能なデータ量はほぼほぼ改善されません。結局、処理方法を抜本的に見直す必要があります。少なくともString結合を無制限に繰り返すことはできません。
必然的にString結合はある程度、少量に抑えられることになるはずですが、その際に作成される文字列が約4万文字以下に抑えられるのであればString結合と`StringBuilder`とにメモリ上の優劣はありません。（4万文字の根拠は、.NETにおいてオブジェクトサイズが85KB未満・以上とで管理方法が異なることに起因します。）
例えば今回であれば、全件を一気に処理せず1件ずつ処理するように見直した方がいいかもしれません。その場合、1件のデータは

> Singleの数値をカンマで区切り、1000個のカンマ区切り文字列

とのことですが、この程度であれば最悪ケースでも1万文字程度に収まります。

---

`StringBuilder`はyhataさんが説明されているように大きな文字列を作成しても85KB未満に収まるように分割管理されているため文字列編集のパフォーマンスに優れます。ただし、これは.NET 4にて改善されたもので、.NET 3.5以前では享受できませんので気を付ける必要があります。その場合どうすべきかというと、予め文字列長を見積もり、`StringBuilder.Capacity`プロパティを設定することです。これにより事前にメモリ確保をし、文字列編集時の逐次メモリ拡張を排除できます。

Comment: 確かに単なる文字列連結にしては時間がかかりすぎている気はしますが、OutOfMemoryExceptionは起こりえます。私も経験しています。LOHはGCがかかっても、コンパクションの対象にはならずメモリが空くわけではありません。たとえ2GBの文字列にならなくとも、 数MBのヒープの空間がたくさん出来て、それより小さいオブジェクトの入れ物として再利用されることが期待されて残ってしまい、メモリの断片化が発生します。
http://needtec.exblog.jp/21581708/

Comment: @yhata 確実なことは言えませんが「Singleの数値をカンマで区切り、1000個」であればLOH（85KB、40,000文字程度）にはならないように思いますが…？ また、たとえLOHに配置され断片化したとしても、次の行に再利用されませんか？

Comment: カンマ区切りの1000個は`SOH`ですが、それを繰り返し`temp_Str`に格納（連結）していくと読めるので、`temp_Str`が`LOH`になります。`temp_Str`は少しずつ肥大化し、メモリは断片化していきます。

Comment: 1000個×数100万回繰り返した場合、Stringでは格納できないがStringBuilderでは格納できるとでも？ どちらであっても2GBを超えますし、1000個であればどちらでも収まるかと。つまり、 @yhata さんの主張されたいことがよくわかりませんでした。

Comment: 1000個×数100万回の試行がメモリに収まるとは言っていません。（payanecoさんの報告の通り）
`temp_Str`は文字列が連結されて大きくなり、LOHに配置されるはずですよね？そして、LOHに対してはGCとコンパクションは必ずしも同時に実行されない、コンパクションが実行されないと使えるメモリ空間は無くなっていく段階を理解する必要があります。https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/

Comment: そんなことはわかっています。そのうえで、質問文通りであれば1000個の結合でありLOHには配置されそうになくStringとStringBuilderとで大差ないと言っています。また仮に質問文が誤っていてそれ以上に結合されるのであれば、確かにStringはLOHの問題により早期にOutOfMemoryExceptionが発生しますが、StringBuilderであってもOutOfMemoryExceptionは避けられません。私としてはStringBuilderはありきたりな回答どころか質問の問題については解決できず、またそうであればLOH問題は関係ないと考えますが、 @yhata さんはStringBuilderを使うことで何を主張されているのですか？

Comment: 質問文の`temp_Str`の使い方の認識に違いがあるようです。`temp_Str = temp_Str + カンマ区切り1000個の文字列`を10万回件以上実行したら`OutOfMemoryException`が発生したと認識しました。そのような経験が私にもありました。そのため、@sayuri さんの「`OutOfMemoryException`は起こりえない。別の原因がある。」の回答は間違っていると考えました。これ以上のやり取りで、そんなことと言われてもなんですので、私からは以上とします。